# How to implement a Lens like Getter for a specific type?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, lenses

Given the general `Getter` type

```
type Getter s a = forall f. (Contravariant f, Functor f) => (a -> f a) -> s -> f s
```

how would I implement a getter for, say, a pair tuple? I guess the above type represents a partially applied function and the missing part is exactly what confuses me.

Beyond that I don't understand the contravariant constraint. It's probably there to make the type more lens like, but isn't functor enough?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the type `Getter s a`, type `s` denotes the "object" that somehow "contains" a value of type `a`, which the getter can somehow "extract" from it.

If you want to implement a getter for a pair, then your `s = (x, y)`, and your `a` would be either `x` or `y`, depending on which element you're extracting. Let's say for clarity that you're extracting the first element. Then `a = x`.

Ok, so your function would look like this:

```
firstElementGetter :: Getter (x, y) x
```

Now, if we expand the definition of `Getter`, we get:

```
firstElementGetter :: (blah-blah) => (x -> f x) -> (x, y) -> f (x, y)
firstElementGetter h (x, y) = ...
```

This means that your function gets two parameters: (1) a function `h` that can "wrap" an `x` in functor `f`, and (2) a tuple `(x, y)`; and it needs to return a tuple `(x, y)` wrapped in the functor `f`. Let's see if we can do that.

First, we have a function `h` that takes a parameter of type `x`. Conveniently, we also have an `x` of that very type. Let's apply it: `h x`. The result of that has type `f x`. How can we turn that into `f (x, y)`?

Well, the very thing of a `Functor` is that you can *map* over it. So what function can we map over `f x` to obtain `f (x, y)`? Such function obviously needs to have a type `x -> (x, y)` - and behold! We have all the parts to construct such a function! We can take our existing `y` and recombine it into the tuple: `\xx -> (xx, y)`.

Now we have everything to fulfill the contract of the getter:

```
firstElementGetter :: (blah-blah) => (x -> f x) -> (x, y) -> f (x, y)
firstElementGetter h (x, y) = fmap (\xx -> (xx, y)) (h x)
```

---

This is, at root, how all optics work - be they getters, traversals, prisms, or whatever. The consumer can then make them do different things by choosing the right functor `f` and the right wrapping function `h`.

For example, the consumer can use your getter to "extract" the first element from a tuple by choosing this functor:

```
data Const a b = Const a

instance Functor (Const a) where
    fmap f (Const a) = Const a
```

Notice how it completely ignores the type `b`. Doesn't actually "wrap" a value of it, and `fmap` implementation doesn't touch it either. You might say it's a "fake" functor. We're going to use that to our advantage!

For function `h` we're going to choose `Const`. It fits the type, because `Const :: x -> Const x foo` for any `foo`, which happens to be compatible with `x -> Const x x`, which matches the required type `x -> f x` when `f = Const x`. I know, this is a bit mind-blowing, but bear with me.

Now, if `h = Const`, our getter will dutifully call `h x`, which would return `Const x`, which the getter will `fmap` over, but since our definition of `fmap` ignores its first argument, the result of `fmap` will still be the very same `Const x`, which the getter will then return. Now, all we need to do is just unwrap it, and we're done!

```
getFirst :: (x, y) -> x
getFirst pair = 
    let (Const x) = firstElementGetter Const pair
    in x
```

---

The `Contravariant` part is a bit of a clever type-level hackery. See, when a functor `f` is not only `Functor`, but also `Contravariant`, it *has* to have the shape of the `Const` type above - i.e. it cannot "wrap" a value of its type parameter inside.

`Functor` can be thought of as a thing that "produces" (or "contains") values, while `Contravariant` is a thing that "consumes" values. If a "wrapper" type has to be both, the only way to implement it is to only pretend to "consume" or "produce" values, but ignore them behind the scenes. I understand this is not a very clear explanation, but I can't do any better. Just try to implement a type like that, you'll see.

So `Getter` is given this weird constraint just as a way to ensure that the only thing it can do is "get" a value, never "set" or "transform" it.

- The simplest implementation of a getter would be just `s -> a`.
- A less simple implementation would be `(a -> x) -> s -> x` - in continuation-passing style, but equivalent to the previous one.
- A yet less simple implementation would be `(a -> Const x a) -> s -> Const x s` - I just replaced both `a` with `Const x foo` with different `foo`, but it's still equivalent to the previous one.

While the first (simplest) definition would do for the actual getting, the last definition has the advantage of having a signature compatible with other lenses, thus making it possible to use such getter in lens compositions.

Comment: While this is a great answer as far as it goes, I don't think you've actually answered the OP's question, which appears to be all about why the `Contravariant` constraint exists for a `Getter`, which you don't appear to have mentioned at all. Your example seems to explain how the `Lens` type works and how you can use one to essentially re-implement the `fst` function - but it doesn't touch on how a `Getter` is different, and in particular why the type is so relaxed to not need to work on all `Functor`s, just those which are also `Contravariant`.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I disagree that the question was "primarily" about `Contravariant`. The question title says "How to implement a Getter", and the first question in the body matches that. It is only after "beyond that" qualification that the OP is asking about `Contravariant`. Nevertheless, I was going to write about it for completeness, just didn't have enough time. Done now.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin apologies, I think I had misread the question when I made that comment. But thank you for subsequently adding the explanation of that part.

Comment: I'd like to clarify a detail: `firstElementGetter` doesn't even use the Contravariant constraint, because it is sufficient that it exists for `f`: `Const a` has an instance but `Identity` hasn't, so every attempt to pass `Identity` as `f` wouldn't type check and thus there is no way of using a Getter as a Setter/transformer.